# Does a PTHREAD mutex only avoid simultaneous access to a resource, or it does anything more?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, multiprocessing, mutex

Example:
A thread finishes writing to a shared variable, and then it unlocks it, but continues to use that variable's value (without changing it).
And immediately, another thread successfully unlocks() that mutex and reads the shared variable.

For my (mis-)understanding, some things could be happening on this situation:

On the WRITER thread:

- A compiler optimization could make the write occur only at some later point
- The written value could be retained in the current CPU core's cache, and flushed to the memory at some later point

On the READER thread:

- The value of the variable may have been read before the mutex lock(), and because of some compiler optimization or just the usual work of the CPU cache, still be considered "already read from memory" and thus, not fetched from the memory again.
- Thus, the value we have here is not the updated one from the other thread.

Does the pthread mutex lock/unlock() functions execute any code to "flush" the current cache to the memory and anything else needed to make sure the current thread is synchronized with everything else (I cannot think of anything else than the cache), or is it just not needed (at least in all known architectures)?

Because if all the mutexes do is just what the name does - mutual exclusion to it's reference - then, if I have thousands of threads dealing with the same data and from my algorithm's point of view, I already know that when one thread is using a variable, no other thread will try to use it at the same time, than it means I don't need a mutex? Or will my code be missing some low level and architecture-specific method(s) implemented inside the PTHREAD library to avoid the problems above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pthreads mutex lock and unlock functions are among the list of functions in POSIX *"...that synchronize thread execution and also synchronize memory with respect to other threads"*.  So yes, they do more than just interlock execution.

Whether or not they need to issue additional instructions to the hardware is of course architecture dependent (noting that almost every modern CPU architecture will *at least* happily reorder reads with respect to each other unless told otherwise), but in every case those functions must act as "compiler barriers" - that is, they ensure that the compiler won't reorder, coalesce or omit memory accesses in situations where it would otherwise be allowed to.

It *is* allowed to have multiple threads reading a shared value without mutual exclusion though - all you need to ensure is that both the writing and reading threads executed some synchronising function between the write and the read.  For example, an allowable situation is to have many reading threads that defer reading the shared state until they have passed a barrier (`pthread_barrier_wait()`) and a writing thread that performs all its writes to the shared state *before* it passes the barrier.  Reader-writer locks (`pthread_rwlock_*`) are also built around this idea.